# Retry in Azure Durable Functions without throwing exceptions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I'm using Azure Durable Functions for a couple of my function apps. Like a function that is responsible for requesting an external API and then poll for updates until the async request has a response. It's working fine but I have a question for the programming model that is used to implement this function. My orchestrator function looks similar to this:

```cs
public static async Task RunOrchestrator([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
{
    // Make the initial request to the external service
    var resume = await context.CallActivityAsync<bool>(nameof(Requester.InitiateRequest), input);
    if (!resume) return;

    // Wait 5 minutes before we start polling for status
    var nowIn5Minutes = context.CurrentUtcDateTime.AddMinutes(5);
    await context.CreateTimer(nowIn5Minutes, CancellationToken.None);

    // Retry up to 10 times in 1 minute intercals
    var retryOptions = new RetryOptions(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), 10);
    
    // Try to fetch the result
    var result = await context.CallActivityWithRetryAsync<string>(nameof(Requester.FetchResult), retryOptions, input);

    // Do something with the result but out of scope for this question
}
```

Everything is, from my understanding, by the book so far. My question is about the implementation of `Requester.FetchResult`:

```cs
public async Task<string> FetchResult([ActivityTrigger] string input, ILogger log, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Try getting a result from the external API
    bool resultIsReady = ...;

    if (resultIsReady)
        return result;
    else
        throw new ApplicationException("not finished");
}
```

If the result is not yet ready, the function throws a new `ApplicationException`. But I would prefer to have the retry mechanism run without throwing exceptions. Is this possible?

Comment: sounds like you are looking for the same as here, so maybe move your thread there https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/586

Comment: You're right. And now that I've read that, there doesn't seem to be a better approach than throwing exceptions right now. I'll follow that thread. Thanks!